# Changegin doctype root element to rss from html using xslt?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to add an rss-doctype to an xml-document rendered using xslt. How do I change the root element?

This is what it currently looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//Netscape Communications//DTD RSS 0.91//EN" "about:legacy-compat">
```

I would like:

```
<!DOCTYPE rss PUBLIC "-//Netscape Communications//DTD RSS 0.91//EN" "about:legacy-compat">
```

Here is my outputnode:

```
<xsl:output
method="xml"
version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8"
doctype-public="-//Netscape Communications//DTD RSS 0.91//EN"
indent="yes"
/>
```

Comment: Do you want only to generate the `<!DOCTYPE` or do you also want to change the nodes?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include a DTD (see http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200405/post70520.html and answer http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200405/post90520.html where David Carlisle points this out). The following is correct syntax - you will need to find a DTD

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"
doctype-system="http://foo.org/dont.know.the.dtd"
doctype-public="-//Netscape Communications//DTD RSS 0.91//EN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
 doctype-system="http://www.silmaril.ie/software/rss2.dtd"
 doctype-public="-//Netscape Communications//DTD RSS 0.91//EN"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <rss>
   <channel/>
  </rss>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when any XML document (not used) is processed with this transformation, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<!DOCTYPE rss
  PUBLIC "-//Netscape Communications//DTD RSS 0.91//EN" "http://www.silmaril.ie/software/rss2.dtd">
<rss>
   <channel/>
</rss>
```